# How to fix "The term 'clist' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet" this error in windows powershell?

Tags: powershell, terminal, chocolatey

[image]

I installed `winfetch` by using `Install-Script winfetch` command, after installing when i run `winfecth` command in PowerShell it gives me this error. I have already installed `chocolatey`  &  I'm using PowerShell in windows terminal.

How can i fix it ?

Comment: Clist is an application (not a cmdlet) and must be installed on the machine.  Powershell error says cmdlet, script or executable.  Clist is an executable.

Comment: How can i install it ? I checked with `pip` `choco` `npm` and `winget` package manager but i didn't get any solution.

Comment: What operating system are you using?  It is part of Z/OS.  It may not be on your path so PS is not finding the command.  If you are on Linux try WhereIs to locate the file from shell : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/whereis-command-in-linux-with-examples/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`clist` and the other deprecated shims have been removed from Chocolatey CLI.  This happened in version 2.0.0 of Chocolatey CLI, and tracked under this issue: https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/2642

You, and also winfetch, should be using `choco list` rather than `clist`, or, if you are actually searching for packages on a remote source, you should be using `choco search`.

In the meantime, while winfetch is updated, you might want to think about downgrading to an earlier version of Chocolatey CLI.  This can be done using:

```
choco upgrade chocolatey --version 1.4.0 --allow-downgrade
```

Comment: You beat me to this one by 30 seconds. 

Comment: Me too! They could also consider TheCakeIsNaOH's clist package, here: https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/clist-shim